# PostSharp version mismatch, looking for the wrong version

Tags: c#, .net, postsharp

I'm getting this exception when building my solution:

`Unhandled exception (4.1.20.0, postsharp.srv.4.0-x86.exe, CLR 4.0.30319.461308, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyLoadException: Cannot find assembly 'postsharp, version=5.0.42.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7'. [Version mismatch]`

I have binding redirect in my app.config:

`<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="PostSharp" publicKeyToken="b13fd38b8f9c99d7" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.20.0" newVersion="4.1.20.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>`

and use configuration host in csproj file:

`<PropertyGroup>
    <PostSharpHostConfigurationFile>app.config</PostSharpHostConfigurationFile>
 </PropertyGroup>`

I can't figure why postsharp is looking for version 5.0.42.0 while I have 4.1.20.0 nuget version in all projects.

Comment: You are most likely referencing PostSharo 5.0.42 in some other project. PostSharp is more strict than MSBuild when it comes to different versions of the same assembly. Almost generally, using one version across all your projects is a best practice.